# Thoth.Json.Net conditional parsing

Tags: f#, f#-data

I have a JSON document that I'm parsing using Thoth.Json.Net. The document has an array containing a set of objects that each have a "type" attribute with a value that identifies their type. Each of these types needs a different decoder so I need to be able to provide some sort of filter based on the value of the "type" attribute. How can I do this?

### Update:

After getting the "hack" that I describe above working, I revisited using the CE and `decodeByType` custom decoder, with each decoder returning a value from a Discriminated Union as mentioned by @tranquillity above. Once I had got my head around all the types the only thing I had to do was to specify the types for the Builder:

```ml
Builder:   type DecoderBuilder () = 
    member __.Bind((decoder:Decoder<'a>), (func:('a -> Decoder<'b>))) = 
      Decode.andThen func decoder
```

This enabled the use of the CE to combine decoders easily as described by @brianberns below. I created a new file for the custom decoders and the Discriminated Union and found that I was able to extract the values from the JSON more closely to the domain model (making unrepresentable state impossible because an error will be returned if the JSON structure is invalid).

All in all cleaner, more functional, and elegant code. Thank you for the help.

Comment: The answer will probably involve writing a custom decoder to decode to a discriminated union. Can you provide a representative sample of the json and what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a Thoth expert, but here's what I'd do. First, I find it easier to combine decoders using a computation expression:

```ml
type DecodeBuilder() =
    member _.Bind(decoder, f) : Decoder<_> =
        Decode.andThen f decoder
    member _.Return(value) =
        Decode.succeed value
    member _.ReturnFrom(decoder : Decoder<_>) =
        decoder

let decode = DecodeBuilder()
```

Then I invented two custom decoders, just as examples, and put them in a map by name. One reverses a string, and one decodes using the ROT13 cipher. Of course, you'll use your own custom decoders here instead:

```ml
let decodeReverse =
    decode {
        let! str = Decode.string
        return str
            |> Seq.rev
            |> Seq.toArray
            |> String
    }

let decodeRot13 =

    let rot13 c =
        if 'a' <= c && c <= 'm' || 'A' <= c && c <= 'M' then
            char (int c + 13)
        elif 'n' <= c && c <= 'z' || 'N' <= c && c <= 'Z' then
            char (int c - 13)
        else c
        
    decode {
        let! str = Decode.string
        return str
            |> Seq.map rot13
            |> Seq.toArray
            |> String
    }

let customDecoders =
    Map [
        "Reverse", decodeReverse
        "Rot13", decodeRot13
    ]
```

Then, custom decoding is just a matter of decoding the "type" field, looking up the corresponding custom decoder, and using it to decode the "value" field:

```ml
let decodeByType =
    decode {
        let! typ = Decode.field "type" Decode.string
        return! Decode.field "value" customDecoders.[typ]
    }
```

Example usage:

```ml
Decode.fromString
    (Decode.array decodeByType)
    """
    [
        {
            "type" : "Reverse",
            "value" : "edcba"
        },
        {
            "type" : "Rot13",
            "value" : "qrpbqr guvf"
        }
    ]
    """
    |> printfn "%A"   // Ok [|"abcde"; "decode this"|]
```

I put the complete program [here](https://gist.github.com/brianberns/2c4177aca19c7f94c805618ffe04d448) for reference.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and elegant reply @brianberns.

I've spent some time playing with it and loved using a CE for working with Decoder combinators. 

In the end I used an intermediate anonymous record to retrieve all the distinct properties as optional and the post-processed them into domain records.